# how to xpath this "Policy" tab in jave selenium

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, xpath

In my selenium automation script, I am trying to click a "Policy" tab in the webpage by its xpath value.

Here is the actual html code:

```
....
<iframe src="/abc/api/public/v1/security/redirect">
    #document 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="ng-scope" ng-app="CFWApp" lang="en">
     <body>
       <div class="container no-padding main-view flex-col">
          ::before
          <cfw-menu class="ng-isolate-scope">
             <div class="security-menu">
                <ul class = "flex-row">
                   <li class="tab ng-scope active" ng-repeat="tab in $ctrl.items" ng-class="{'active': $ctrl.active == $index}" ui-sref="policy.templateList" href="#!/policy/template" style="">
                      <span class="tab-icon">...</span>
                      <span class='ng-binding'>Policy</span>
                   </li>
                   <li> ... </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
           </cfw-menu>
       ...
       </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

And here is my Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[starts-with(@class = 'tab') and contains(@ui-sref = 'policy.templateList')]/span[2]")).click();
```

But somehow, this xpath setting not working.  Can someone help me for that ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start you need to move to iframe

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
driver.switchTo().frame(popframe);
```

After, you can use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Policy']")).click();
```

But you need to be sure is not more `span`s which have text 'Policy' in that frame.

Answer (score 0):

policy.templateList')]/span[2]")).click()

It will not work as you are trying to click a span element not the button.

Once I also trapped in such type of  problem in python  and then I use  action class  in selenium

First of all select any thing then by selenium action class pass tab key untill you get that element focused then pass enter key using action class that's it.

Good luck...

Comment: You can click on any element and it work if exist an action on it.

Comment: Yeah you are right but here actually not work as it didn't have it